# R: Fill in Implicit Missing Values and Groups to the Entire Time Span of the Data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, missing-data, tibble

**Objective**: 
Fill in implicit missing values for each ID and each *group* over the entire time span of the data, including ***groups that are entirely missing*** from the dataset.

**Background**: 
Each ID has several groups, and each group should have values for each day. However, some values are missing certain dates (such as 1b 2019-01-01), and **some groups are entirely missing** from the dataset (such as 2b).

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     ID group date       value
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 a     2019-01-01     1
2     1 a     2019-01-02     3
3     1 a     2019-01-03     4
4     1 b     2019-01-02     4
5     1 b     2019-01-03     5
6     2 a     2019-01-01     8
7     2 a     2019-01-02     9
8     2 a     2019-01-03     1
```

Code to generate the dataframe

```r
df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
             group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
             date = c('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02','2019-01-03', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03'),
             value = c(1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8, 9, 1))
```

Attempt 1:

```r
library(tsibble)
df %>% 
  # tsibble format
  as_tsibble(key = c(ID, group), index = date) %>%
  # group by
  group_by(ID, group) %>%
  # fill gaps
  fill_gaps(.full = TRUE)
```

Attempt 2:

```r
library(tidyverse)
complete(df, expand(df, nesting(ID, group), date = full_seq(date,1)))
```

Both yield the same result: note that ***group 2b is missing***

```r
# A tsibble: 9 x 4 [1D]
# Key:       ID, group [3]
# Groups:    ID, group [3]
     ID group date       value
  <dbl> <chr> <date>     <dbl>
1     1 a     2019-01-01     1
2     1 a     2019-01-02     3
3     1 a     2019-01-03     4
4     1 b     2019-01-01    NA
5     1 b     2019-01-02     4
6     1 b     2019-01-03     5
7     2 a     2019-01-01     8
8     2 a     2019-01-02     9
9     2 a     2019-01-03     1
```

I expect the output to be

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 4
      ID group date       value
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
 1     1 a     2019-01-01     1
 2     1 a     2019-01-02     3
 3     1 a     2019-01-03     4
 4     1 b     2019-01-01     NA
 5     1 b     2019-01-02     4
 6     1 b     2019-01-03     5
 7     2 a     2019-01-01     8
 8     2 a     2019-01-02     9
 9     2 a     2019-01-03     1
10     2 b     2019-01-01     NA
11     2 b     2019-01-02     NA
12     2 b     2019-01-03     NA
```

where **group b**, which is **implicitly missing** from the dataset, appears in the result.

Note that my dataset has eight million rows and it keeps growing every day. The code will be executed every day so I am really looking forward to a **fast** and convenient way of performing the task. But any idea or answer is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your second attempt is very close to what you expect, but need to replace `nesting()` with `crossing()`. `nesting()` only looks for the combinations appeared in the data, but `crossing()` looks for all possible combinations.

```r
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
             group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
             date = as.Date(c('2019-01-01', '2019-01-02','2019-01-03', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03')),
             value = c(1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8, 9, 1))
complete(df, expand(df, crossing(ID, group), date = full_seq(date, 1)))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>       ID group date       value
#>    <dbl> <chr> <date>     <dbl>
#>  1     1 a     2019-01-01     1
#>  2     1 a     2019-01-02     3
#>  3     1 a     2019-01-03     4
#>  4     1 b     2019-01-01    NA
#>  5     1 b     2019-01-02     4
#>  6     1 b     2019-01-03     5
#>  7     2 a     2019-01-01     8
#>  8     2 a     2019-01-02     9
#>  9     2 a     2019-01-03     1
#> 10     2 b     2019-01-01    NA
#> 11     2 b     2019-01-02    NA
#> 12     2 b     2019-01-03    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly for me. **One suggestion: adding an example of crossing in the complete{tidyr} R Documentation** would be so helpful. I know there must be a function doing this, but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: They have the example on the `expand()` page.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dataframe containing the cartesian product of unique values of ID, group and date, then merge that with the original dataframe to obtain the desired result.

```
zz <- merge(merge(unique(df$ID), unique(df$group), by = NULL, all = TRUE), 
            unique(df$date), by = NULL, all = TRUE)
merge(df, zz, by.x = c('ID','group', 'date'), by.y = c('x','y.x', 'y.y'), all = TRUE)
```

It's expensive, of course, if you have a large number of components and dates. You could, in that case, first merge the ID/group combination against your original dataframe to obtain just the missing combinations, then merge that against the set of dates, again picking up only the missing combinations, if you catch my drift.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! My data frame has 8 million rows, and is growing every day. Running the cartesian product will probably take a while. Other than the size of the data, the code will need to be executed every day (and the ID is changing since some ID could be dropped or added). So I am really looking forward to a fast and convenient way of doing this. I really appreciated your help and I will give it a try when the data is available. Do you have any other recommendations that are quick?